# Aurelia does not update bound value when using jquery attr

Tags: aurelia

I'm updating a data- attribute on an html-element:

```
    $element.attr('data-x', 500);
```

The "data-x" property is bound in the view:

```
<div class="cell" data-x.bind="aViewModelProperty">
```

And the Aurelia viewmodel has a "propertyChanged" method which never triggers:

```
aViewModelPropertyChanged(newValue) {
    alert(newValue);
}
```

When the view loads, the value is correctly read from the viewmodel and into the data-x attribute in the DOM. If the value of the data-x attribute is updated (using the first "attr"-statement), the value is never pushed to the viewmodel, so binding seems to be one-way.

The use-case is that I have a 3rd party lib which updates data- attributes on the DOM directly, I want those changes to be pushed to the viewmodel which has properties bound to the data- attributes.

Note:

Explicity specifying two-way binding produces this error:

ERROR [app-router] Error: Observation of a "LABEL" element's "data-x" property is not supported.(…)

Darn..

Comment: if you have the property, why not using `this.x = item.x` instead of jQuery attr?

Comment: I don't have the property

Comment: The attribute name is `data-x.bind`, not `data-x`. But setting it from outside the aurelia world does not trigger reeavluation. See this example where after 3 sec I change the value from the initial value "initial" to "new". If you inspect the DOM you can see that after 3 seconds it says that `value.bind` is 'new' but the view is not updated (`<e1 value.bind="'new'" class="au-target" au-target-id="2">initial</e1>`). gist.run/?id=88c2a87d9e7fcfc9789476be27460093